# Flutter (iOS) app start and stops with crash

Tags: ios, flutter

I have developed a Flutter Android app and that is working fine. Now I am working on the iOS side. I have configured Firebase and notification APN etc. When I run the app by attaching the real device the app got installed but it just crashes and closes. There are no logs in the console of Android studio.

It just prints below logs.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sign's iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode 
project: ABCD7AUXYZ
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           78.0s
Installing and launching...
```

Where can I find more logs about the crash?

Comment: You cannot see IOS log on Android Studio, The recomended for IOS is opening ios folder in Xcode and run from their.

Comment: Can you not run this from Xcode instead of from Android Studio? That would point you towards the crash I would think. Disclaimer: I have no experience with Flutter :)

Comment: I  really don't have an idea about running Flutter project from Xcode. I will look into that and upside the question. Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Did you add the App Transport Security values to Info PList to allow network?

Answer (score 0):

When I build the project using the Xcode (Thanks to @**Blasanka** & @**Kevin Renskers**) I was able to find out the issue. Actually I was missing the Admob id in the plist file and the internet permission (thanks to @**Stephen J)**.

thanks you for your time and help.